# Jboss BRMS return multiple facts for one input

Tags: redhat-brms

I have a requirement to return all matching rows (or facts or objects) in Guided decision table.But if i put same condition in guided decision table then it give me warning of having duplicate conditions or only one row executes.
Could you please suggest how to return multiple rows from guided decision table or using drl file or any other way.

For Example:

We have a requirement to return multiple objects based upon a certain parameter.

For Example: 
We have two data objects.
Input : source
Output: code,name
Requirement:

### source   code   name

A          c1       X 
A          c2       Y

so if user provide in input source="A", Both object of matching rows should be returned.Output("c1","x") and Output("c2","y")

By putting this in Guided decision table , it says duplicate condition for source.

Could you please suggest the best possible to do this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I think Hit Policy Rule Order could help solve your problem. See the screenshot: [image: Rule Order Hit Policy]